# jQuery hover text effect flip (slide up)

Tags: jquery, text, hover, slide, effect

How would this text effect be created using jQuery...as seen on www.barrettnsmith.com?
I thought I saw a sample somewhere, but now I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 1):

The site you mentioned used flash, but here's a tutorial on achieving the same effect with jQuery

[Animating Navigation](http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/animate-navigation-with-css-jquery/)

Comment: You're welcome - if you've found this answer helpful, please consider accepting it as your answer.

Comment: The link is broken.  Can you find the tutorial and post a complete answer here, with the link for reference?

Comment: Honestly, I can't remember what the effect was. The source site is no longer using flash, so it doesn't display the desired effect anymore.